# I need help interpreting a diversion curve diagram (transport economics)

Tags: demand, transportation

In my handbook of transport economics (Blauwens, De Baere, Van de Voorde, 2020), while discussing infrastructure assignment and the diversion curve method, the following diagram is shown (minus "the 4km saved - 5 min. lost" annotation, the image is from the course slides):

[image]

I've been unable to figure out what exactly the curves stand for and the adjoining discussion in the handbook isn't really clear and even contradictory. Quoting the book text:

> [Figure] consists of a number of diversion curves representing the share of a motorway in traffic between two zones as a continuous function of travel time and distance saved in comparison with an alternative route.

> In a 50 %-diversion curve, one tries to achieve combinations of time and distance saved that will result in a 50%-share for the motorway. In the case of [figure], this combination is 4 kilometres saved and 5 minutes lost. The curve has a negative slope: greater distance gains are compensated by time loss, so that a given share is retained.

> In the case of a motorway, all points on a 60%-curve are more favourable than those on a 50%-curve.

It seems to say that the percentage refers to the relative shares with which 2 alternative routes are used. Searching elsewhere for discussion of diversion curves (eg: https://jawaharlalcolleges.com/downloads/CE/S8/CE%20472/CE%20472%20MODULE%205.pdf) seems to confirm that this would be the case (as diversion curves diagrams typically show the % with which an alternative is used on one axis vs time or distance saved on the other axis). However, I can't make sense of the statement "one tries to achieve combinations of time and distance saved that will result in a 50%-share for the motorway" in this regard. If we're comparing 2 alternative routes, then how can there be combinations of time and distance saved for a given %-share? After all, the motorway isn't getting shorter or longer. It seems to me that distance and time saved should simply be a dot on the diagram, for any given %-share. The only curve should be a single one connecting those dots.

Below I've added the images of 2 more slides that were part of the discussion of the diversion curve, featuring an example, though I don't find it helpful. It seems to confirm we're comparing 2 alternative routes, but gives no indication of how you can have a curve of combinations of distance saved and time saved with a given %-share.

[image]
[image]